# Making multiple pendrives bootable, using command-line

Tags: boot, usb, mount, usb-drive

How can I create multiple bootable pen-drives at the same time using Command-Line? For information, the normal flow of making a bootable pendrive using terminal is as follows:

1: Check the pen drive device name.

```
lsblk
```

2: Unmount and Format the pendrive.

```
sudo umount /dev/sdc1
sudo mkfs.vfat -n 'Ubuntu' -I /dev/sdc1
```

3:Burn it bootable using th iso file.

```
sudo dd bs=4M if=/home/bbnladmin/Desktop/ISO /ubuntu-12.04.iso of=/dev/sdb1 && sync
```

Now how can we go for burning multiple pen-drives at a time in this way?

Comment: Why you don't give feedback for your questions?! Why you just asked and go away?! You can have to reply and mark answers when it's valid...  take a look http://askubuntu.com/tour

Comment: @Maythux : Thanks for the advice. Will follow these hereforth..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the dd command can pipe its output do several devices in one run through tee like discribed here:

https://joshhead.wordpress.com/2011/08/04/multiple-output-files-with-dd-utility/

TLDR!:

```
sudo su
dd if=inputfileimage.bin | tee >(dd of=/dev/sdc) | dd of=/dev/sdh
```

would write the file "inputfileimage.bin" to the devices sdc and sdh in a root console...

**be carefull** - dd won't ask if you really chose the right devices - you must be sure that in this example **sdc** and **sdh** should be completely wiped!